# Fish Tank water change

Tags: fish, tetra

How soon can I return My tetras to their tank after a water change. I have changed 50% of my tank water and want to know when I can return my fish to the tank.

Comment: I believe your answer is in this existing question [How do I do a water change in my fish tank?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5470), you don't take the fish out, you just take some water out and put new water in.

Comment: That depends on why you did such a large water change and why you removed the fish.  Were the nitrates too high?  What are the parameters now?  If your tank was properly cycled, you're running a good risk of recycling it by having removed all of the fish.  I'll quit speculating now but you need to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks. I have discovered that I am getting too  anxious with the tank. I think I've got it sort of figured out.

Comment: Jonathan - could you edit your question with some of the extra information you've figured out so it can become an excellent question?